# How to read .pkl file to a tokenizer object?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pickle, tokenize

I use

```
 pickle.dump(tokenizer, open(TOKENIZER_MODEL, "wb"), protocol=0)
```

to generate a .pkl file, when I trying to read it using

`pickle.load(open('tokenizer.pkl'))`

it raises

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

but when I trying to change this object to bytes-like object using

```
tkr = open('tokenizer.pkl')
bytes(tkr,encoding='utf-8')
```

it raises

> TypeError: encoding without a string argument

I was wodering that if there is anyway to read this .pkl file or io.TextIOWrapper file to a tokenizer object?

Comment: Never used pickle but I think that this line `pickle.load(open('tokenizer.pkl'))` should be  `pickle.load(open('tokenizer.pkl', 'rb'))`

Comment: Did you try opening your file in byte mode? Like this: `pickle.load(open('tokenizer.pkl', 'rb'))`. The `r` stands for read and `b` for bytes

Answer (score 0):

When you want to read the file you need to write

```
file = open('tokenizer.pkl', 'rb')    
pickle.load(file)
```

- 'r' stands for *read mode*
- 'b' stands for *binary mode*

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've never used pickle but after trying it really quickly in repl.it I think that your problem is in this line

```
pickle.load(open('tokenizer.pkl'))
```

It should be

```
pickle.load(open('tokenizer.pkl','rb'))
```